# Changing background-color of header is not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

Hello this is my first question on stackoverflow so excuse my inexperience.

I am trying to change the background color of an entire HTML document using background-color on the element  although some of the document changes color, I can't change the  background-color, I tried changing it with inline css on the element and it's not working, yet I can change the height attribute.

This is bugging me for hours and I am confused.

This is my first ASP.net Core Web Application using MVC model so I am using the automatically generated file "_Layout.cshtml"

```
 <body style="background-color: #767678;">
<header style="background-color: #767678; height:100px;">


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MovieLover</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index">Movies</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <img src="https://users.iee.ihu.gr/~it174985/imgs/search.svg" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <input type="text" value="Search" style="margin-top:5px; width:600px" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I also post a picture of the website so you can see how it looks. => [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TLpq.png)

Thank you all for your time any answer will be appreciated

Comment: do u checked css for navbar class ?? also remove class navbar-light and bg-white from nav and try

Comment: Thank you very much i removed the navbar-light and bg-white from class and it's working!

Comment: From this fix I can tell this was a css priority problem, I suppose the nav prioritized the css it got from the class rather than the inline css but shoudn't it be the other way arround? prioritizing the inline css over the css it inherits because of class?

Comment: no.. it is not priority issue....Your header inline css is working... but you placed navbar above header... so header color is on backside of nav. nav bg color was from class nav-light and bg-white. It is just like header layer beneath nav layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Dr J Manish reply the problem was fixed all I had to do was remove navbar-light and bg-white from the nav element

Comment: it is great to know that your problem is fixed.